# Why do my pyramids fade black and then back to colour again

Tags: 3d, opengl-es, ios, xcode

I have the following vertecies and norms

```
GLfloat verts[36] = {

-0.5, 0, 0.5,
 0, 0, -0.5,
0.5, 0, 0.5,

0, 0, -0.5,
0.5, 0, 0.5,
0, 1, 0,

-0.5, 0, 0.5,
0, 0, -0.5,
0, 1, 0,

0.5, 0, 0.5,
-0.5, 0, 0.5,
0, 1, 0

};

GLfloat norms[36] = {

0, -1, 0,
0, -1, 0,
0, -1, 0,

-1, 0.25, 0.5,
-1, 0.25, 0.5,
-1, 0.25, 0.5,

1, 0.25, -0.5,
1, 0.25, -0.5,
1, 0.25, -0.5,

0, -0.5, -1,
0, -0.5, -1,
0, -0.5, -1 
};
```

I am writing my fists Open GL game, But I need to know for sure if my Normals are correct as the colours aren't rendering correctly. my Pyramids are coloured then fade to black every half rotation then back again.

[image: coloured]
[image: Black]

---

My app so far is based on the boiler plate code provided by apple. heres my modified setUp Method

```
 [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

[self loadShaders];

self.effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];
self.effect.light0.enabled = GL_TRUE;
self.effect.light0.diffuseColor = GLKVector4Make(1.0f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1.0f);

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);


glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray); //create vertex array
glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts) + sizeof(norms), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW); //create vertex buffer big enough for both verts and norms and pass NULL as data..
uint8_t *ptr = (uint8_t *)glMapBufferOES(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY_OES); //map buffer to pass data to it
memcpy(ptr, verts, sizeof(verts)); //copy verts
memcpy(ptr+sizeof(verts), norms, sizeof(norms)); //copy norms to position after verts
glUnmapBufferOES(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0)); //tell GL where verts are in buffer
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(verts))); //tell GL where norms are in buffer
glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
```

And the update method.

```
- (void)update
{

float aspect = fabsf(self.view.bounds.size.width / self.view.bounds.size.height);
GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(65.0f), aspect, 0.1f, 100.0f);

self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = projectionMatrix;

GLKMatrix4 baseModelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, -4.0f);
baseModelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(baseModelViewMatrix, _rotation, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

// Compute the model view matrix for the object rendered with GLKit
GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.5f);
modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrix, _rotation, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(baseModelViewMatrix, modelViewMatrix);

self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = modelViewMatrix;

// Compute the model view matrix for the object rendered with ES2
modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.5f);
modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrix, _rotation, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(baseModelViewMatrix, modelViewMatrix);

_normalMatrix = GLKMatrix3InvertAndTranspose(GLKMatrix4GetMatrix3(modelViewMatrix), NULL);

_modelViewProjectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(projectionMatrix, modelViewMatrix);

_rotation += self.timeSinceLastUpdate * 0.5f;
}
```

But providing I understand this correct one pyramid is using the GLKit base effect shaders and the other the shaders which are included in the project. So for both of them to have the same error, I thought it would be the Norms?

Comment: Do you know where your light is?  The problem probably isn't in your normals themselves but in how you're using them in your pipeline.  (Although it's worth noting that those 'normals' aren't actually normalized - that is, their lengths aren't 1 - so that could be part of the issue.  In short, the information you've given us so far isn't nearly enough to diagnose your problem.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thanks for taking the time. I have added further detail.

Comment: I just tried adding `vec3 n = normalize(normal);` into my vertex shader but it had no effect. Perhaps its not the normals after all

Comment: Try drawing your normals (in the center of the triangle as `(n1+n2+n3)/3` which in this case is the same as n1, but later it might not be) and the light (source + direction) as lines directly into the scene and see if everything lines up. You might have simply flipped a normal inside out, which is hard to see with only their number-vector-representation.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer: it was the Normals:

GLfloat norms[36] = {

```
0, -1, 0,
0, -1, 0,
0, -1, 0,

1, 0.25, -0.5,
1, 0.25, -0.5,
1, 0.25, -0.5,

-1, 0.25, -0.5,
-1, 0.25, -0.5,
-1, 0.25, -0.5,

0, 0.5, 1,
0, 0.5, 1,
0, 0.5, 1
};
```

These are the correct ones. For some reason the maths I used produced some numbers that were negative when they shouldn't have been. thanks for all the help! GC